# CSS transition working in Safari but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

For some reason, this code works in Safari but not Chrome. In Safari the hamburger button animates into the X. In Chrome it just snaps between the two states. Am I missing something obvious or am I using a property that Chrome doesn't support?

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.menu-button');

el.onclick = function() {
  el.classList.toggle('toggled');
}
```

```css
.menu-button {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.menu-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-button .line {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transition: margin 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, transform 0.2s ease-in-out 0;
}

.menu-button .line:last-child {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.menu-button.toggled .line {
  transition-delay: 0, 0.2s;
  transition-property: margin, transform;
}

.menu-button.toggled .line:first-child {
  margin-top: 2px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-button.toggled .line:last-child {
  margin-top: -2px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-button">
  <div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
transition: margin 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, transform 0.2s ease-in-out 0;
```

Should be:

```
transition: margin 0.2s ease-in-out, transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
```

**EDIT:**

It works in chrome if you add an `s` to the final `0`:

```
transition: margin 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, transform 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
```

Comment: That second number is the transition delay timing, which is important to get the animation desired.

Comment: Well it worked in chrome as soon as I removed them. It is what is breaking it. You can use `transition-delay` to create the desired delay

Comment: Ah try changing the last `0` to `0s`